# Forms Builder showing MaxValue

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm new to Oracle Forms Builder and I want to display only the max Value of a column. How can I do this?

Comment: You write a query which selects `max(your_column_name)` from your table and display it in your Form.

Answer (score 0):

I presume

- You created a `Data Block`(*let's call* `emp`) which has a `Query Data Source Name` (*assume
  Oracle's famous `emp` table*)

  with `Multiple Records Displayed`,

  and of type `Tabular`.
- Add a *max_empno* to the *Data Block* `emp`, under the item *empno*

  with `Number of Items Displayed` property set to 1,

  `Database Item` property set to `No`,

  `Calculation Mode` property set to `Summary`,

  `Summary Function` property set to `Max`,

  `Summarized Block` is `emp`,

  `Summarized Item` is `empno`.

[image]

- and setting `Query All Records` property of the block `emp` to `Yes`
  shouldn't be forgotten. Then, When the form module is run, the
  following interface will appear :

[image]